# How to switch audio from computer to TV (hdmi)?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, hdmi, tv, playback

At the moment my laptop is connected to the TV via hdmi. Both devices are active and can play sounds.

Although I'm quite tech savvy, audio has never been my forte. My conundrum is this: While watching a stream video, the flash player on Firefox plays the sound on the laptop, while on Chrome it plays the sound on the TV.

I've fiddled about the playback devices, but all I can do is set the default device, which accomplishes nothing.

1. Any ideas why and how to change where a certain app plays its sound?
2. Is it possible to have a setup where the audio would switch to the device where the window is moved? (as in, when I move the window from the laptop screen to the TV, I want the TV to automatically take the sound over, and vice-versa)

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [AudioSwitcher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/audioswitcher/) [freeware/donationware] for a long time to do this.

It isn't automatic, but can be triggered by hotkey or from a taskbar popup  to swap audio outputs on the fly - no relaunch required.

I've never tested it on HDMI but it works perfectly well when I forget to switch outputs from iTunes - RCA stereo; to VLC - analog 5.1 before launching.

Previously, I'd have to quit, swap outputs, re-launch ... tedious.

Comment: Does it switch all audio, or only the active window?

Comment: I've never tested that - the particular machine I use it on really only ever runs iTunes & VLC, it's not a general-purpose machine.